# Multiple Virtual Hosts on Different Ports in WAMP

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

So I have this problem...

I use WAMP and have set up perfectly working Virtual Hosts in the past, but now I have come to something I never foresaw.

I am trying to do this:

Access C:\wamp\www through http://localhost

Access D:\somethingelse through http://localhost:8080 OR http://something.dev

I much prefer using the proper http://something.dev, as the working site is http://something.co, and so I can keep them separate.

I have followed guides and read forum posts, but all I have manages to do so far is this:

Access C:\wamp\www through http://localhost OR http://something.dev

Access D:\somethingelse through http://localhost:8080 OR http://something.dev:8080

Anybody got any idea how you would do this? Here's my VirtualHost Code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias www.localhost.com
ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerAdmin webmaster@something
DocumentRoot "D:/something/www"
ServerName something.dev
ServerAlias www.something.dev
ErrorLog "logs/something-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/something-access.log" common
<directory "D:/something/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in httpd.conf I have this

```
Listen *:80
Listen *:8080
```

And my hosts file is working and points both of these to 127.0.0.1

(The reason I want to do this is that when I code on my machine I use the http://something.dev, but I run Livereload Windows, and test my website simultaneously on an iPhone and iPad on the same local network, but without any access to iOS's equivalent of the hosts file. It also allows me to open up only a specific part of my server to the internet, through port forwarding on my router.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose you have solved the issue. Anyway is good to share some nice information on how to set up multiple Virtual Hosts in Wamp. This is working for me:

http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

In my case I am working with ports 8080 and 8181. 8080 is redirecting to a subfolder under c:\wamp\www\myfolder, while 8181 is redirecting to root c:\wamp\www.

To make 8181 work I had to edit httpd-vhosts.conf, hosts (in \drivers\etc folder) and httpd.conf.

In httpd.conf my Apache is listening:

```
Listen 8080
Listen 8181
```

also I uncommented:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

my root is pointing to

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/myfolder"
```

root directory is configured as:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

and added:

```
<VirtualHost *:8181>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
ServerName name-of-my-fake-server
</VirtualHost>
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf I have set:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8181
```

in hosts (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) I have added:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       name-of-my-fake-server #My Test Site
```

Doing that I have now two ports working 8080 and 8181: so 8080 points to directory `"c:\wamp\www\myfolder"` and the other port 8181 points to my root folder `"c:\wamp\www\"`

Answer (score 1):

Using * as the hostname requires the use of NameVirtualHost:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

Comment: NameVirtualHost is not used in the newest version of Wampserver.

Answer (score 0):

For those with MAMP, edit the `httpd.conf`

```
nano /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
```

Add `Listen` for each port

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

And the `ServerName` too

```
ServerName localhost:80
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Once done that, edit `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
nano /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Define `NameVirtualHost`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

And the `VirtualHost`'s

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourUser/path/project1"
    ServerName project1.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourUser/path/project2"
    ServerName project2.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course you need to have `project1.local` and `project2.local` in your `hosts` file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

And add

```
127.0.0.1 project1.local project2.local
```

Restart MAMP and you could access your vhost by

```
project1.local
project2.local:8080
```

`project2` could be access also in your network or with a external IP (e.g to test from a different device like a mobile phone). Assuming your IP is `192.168.1.10`

```
192.168.1.10:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

**The question is a little about it. But I assumed that it's near there and may be helpful for somebody.**

Recently I met the problem when I need to **get access to a few resources** (debian repository, my website and phpmyadmin) by **one external IP address** and port.

After learning the problem I found technology named as `reverse proxy`. It like proxy but server is accepting all connection from many users and redirect to one target (your server).

I made simple Docker image and **docker-compose** file and push that to [github.com/urpylka/docker-nginx-reverse-proxy](https://github.com/urpylka/docker-nginx-reverse-proxy) and [hub.docker.com](https://cloud.docker.com/u/smirart/repository/docker/smirart/nginx-reverse-proxy).

Config file is very simple:

```sh
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     smirart.ru robotic.lol;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://robotic.lol:1080/;
    }
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     repo.smirart.ru;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://8.8.8.8:2080/;
    }
}
```

You can use that for few web-servers running by different IP.

Comment: That's not what the question was about.

Comment: Yes, but the task (access C:\wamp\www through http://localhost & access D:\somethingelse through http://something.dev) may be solved by my method. And I assumed this can be helpful for somebody. And it can use different ports)